# How to add new elements to a list in a for loop, without resetting the list

Tags: r

My question is a bit complicated so let me try and explain

I have data frame of length y with one column of genomic ranges. I am trying to add a second column to denote the sample name that they came from. My data frame consists of ranges compiled from 80+ samples.

```
  range
1 chr1_630186_630400
2 chr1_633734_634177
3 chr1_778372_779915
4 chr1_806338_806694
5 chr1_827261_827986
6 chr1_869762_870290
7 chr1_935164_935710
```

I also have a list of the sample names `namelist`

```
sample1, sample2, sample3, ..... sample_n
```

As well as how many ranges each of these samples has `lengthlist`

```
3, 2, 2
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is use all of these elements to create a dataframe column that denotes the sample that the ranges come from i.e.

```
  range                  sample
1 chr1_630186_630400     sample1
2 chr1_633734_634177     sample1
3 chr1_778372_779915     sample1
4 chr1_806338_806694     sample2
5 chr1_827261_827986     sample2
6 chr1_869762_870290     sample3
7 chr1_935164_935710     sample3
```

Here is my code

```
x=1

datasetlist <- c()
namelist <- rownames(metaData)
for(i in lengthlist)
    datasetlist <- append(rep(namelist[x],i), datasetlist)
    
    x=x+1

    datasetlist
```

However, this simply returns a list of length y (same as the data frame) of the first element in `namelist`. Any idea why this is? what can i do to change it?

Comment: It is much easier to help if you provide sample data. Please share the `metaData`, `namelist`, `lengthlist`and the `"data frame of length y with one column of genomic ranges"` objects. You can use `dput(metaData)` and paste the output inside the question. If the objects are too big, use a subset, like in `dput(head(metaData, 7))`

Comment: metaData is simply a list of sample names

Comment: whether it is simple or complex, is irrelevant. If we are going to run your code to test it, we should be able to reproduce your results, and we cant do that without the actual objects used in this for loop transformation

Answer (score 0):

Not a true answer to your question but using `rep()` you could achieve your desired result like so:

```r
dat <- structure(list(range = c(
  "chr1_630186_630400", "chr1_633734_634177",
  "chr1_778372_779915", "chr1_806338_806694", "chr1_827261_827986",
  "chr1_869762_870290", "chr1_935164_935710"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
))

namelist <- paste0("sample", 1:3)
lengthlist <- c(3, 2, 2)

dat |>
  transform(sample = rep(namelist, lengthlist))
#>                range  sample
#> 1 chr1_630186_630400 sample1
#> 2 chr1_633734_634177 sample1
#> 3 chr1_778372_779915 sample1
#> 4 chr1_806338_806694 sample2
#> 5 chr1_827261_827986 sample2
#> 6 chr1_869762_870290 sample3
#> 7 chr1_935164_935710 sample3
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data provided in [@Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77581576/20002111) all youd need to do is

```
dat$sample <- rep(x = namelist, times = lengthlist)
```

**Data**

```
dat <- structure(list(
  range = c("chr1_630186_630400", "chr1_633734_634177", "chr1_778372_779915", 
            "chr1_806338_806694", "chr1_827261_827986", "chr1_869762_870290", 
            "chr1_935164_935710")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
namelist <- paste0("sample", 1:3)
lengthlist <- c(3, 2, 2)
```